# sharred preference null pointer exception

Tags: android

```
//Activity-- mTweetApp.SetCaseInfo(type,teet); //storing in another class

public void SetCaseInfo(String PatientType,ArrayList arr){
   // All objects are from 
   SharedPreferences settings =setSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS,0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
   editor.putInt("arrayLength",arr.size());
   for(int i=0; i<=arr.size(); i++){
      editor.putInt("Teethsselected"+String.valueOf(i), (Integer) arr.get(i));
   }
   editor.putString("view", PatientType);
   for(int i=0; i<=arr.size(); i++){
       System.out.println("Teethsselected-----"+(Integer) arr.get(i)+"type--->"+PatientType);
   }
}

public void getCaseInfo() {
   SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS, 0);
   int arraySize = settings.getInt("arrayLength", 0); 
   int teeth[] =new int[arraySize];
   for(int i=0; i<arraySize; i++){
      teeth[i] = ettings.getInt("Teethsselected"+String.valueOf(i),0);
   } 
   String type =settings.getString("view"," ");
}
```

how to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to read this code without any formatting.  If you check the exception in logcat, it should point to the specific line number where the NPE is occurring.  If you're still stuck, clean up the code around that line and let us know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Please reformat your code. I'd normally do it for you, but it looks like you've got absolutely *no* formatting here. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: can't see anything of your code, you might want to re-format it.

Comment: I agree with spatulamania, in case you do not know how to see logcat output, try `adb logcat` in a shell, then launch your activity again.

Comment: mTweetApp.SetCaseInfo(type,teet); NPE

Comment: when i call setcaseinfo to store my value,setcaseinfo i tried to print value of  System.out.println("Teethsselected-----"+(Integer) arr.get(i)+"type--->"+PatientType);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you write your `pref` values, no call of `commit()`. 
Second, the pref file is not written to `/data/data/com.package.App/shared_prefs/pref_file.xml`, hence when reading the `SharedPreferences` object is NULL.

Answer (score 3):

You don't commit your changes. put `editor.commit();` into your set method.

Comment: Change setSharedPreferences to getSharedPreferences. Like ntc answered below.

Comment: What is the exact line of the exception?

Comment: setcaseinfo(type,teet); am passing my values in this lin am getting NPE,type is my string value and arraylist object is teet

Comment: Try logging those variables and if the problem isn't there. try logging everything else in setcaseinfo method to see what is null. Your sharedpreferences handling should be fine if you did the changes mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences.Editor modifications should be `commit`ed.

```
   //Your code
   editor.putString("view", PatientType);
   for(int i=0; i<=arr.size(); i++){
       System.out.println("Teethsselected-----"+(Integer) arr.get(i)+"type--->"+PatientType);
   }
   //ADD THIS
   editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences settings =setSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS,0);
```

instaed of above line, try using

```
SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences(DEALSPOTR_PREFS,0);
```

and don't forget `editor.commit()` line once the values are added..